# How to install an older version of HDF5 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I need [HDF5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/) [1.8.12](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/support/HDF5+1.8.12) specifically on my machine.

How can I install this particular version on it? There doesn't seem to be an option to do so using `apt-get`.

Can I just download it from [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.8/hdf5-1.8.12/obtain51812.html) and copy/merge the folders to my `/usr/` ?

Comment: Their installation packages look pretty CentOS/RedHat specific. Have you considered virtualizing and adding a CentOS VM?

Comment: @K7AAY that sounds complicated. There must have been a release for Ubuntu at some point (in fact matlab 2019b uses that version). So my question is not how to install those, but how to install that version HDF5, regardless of where it comes from

Comment: If you want to check for an Ubuntu release, you will need to contact the developer. When I looked in _man_, I only found a tool for HDF5 http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/h5dump.1.html and a search at https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/allpackages only found https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libhdf5-serial-dev plus https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libhdf5-doc and other tools. Would those help?